Flight Rescheduled - How to get Compensation?
Me and a wife booked a flight ticket to an EU country with one connection in Athens. Months ago, the first leg of the journey got cancelled but the airline could rebook us to a flight with two connections. Now, less than two weeks before the flight, the first leg of our journey got rescheduled by two hours which makes it virtually impossible for us to make the connection (25 minutes layover with passport control as we will enter the Schengen area in Athens).
On their website the airline offers us the possibility to reschedule to a day later, I think if I call them they might also be able to rebook us to another airport not too far away from our original final destination. What is the correct way to do in order to take a flight through the airline but also be entitled to 2x400 Euro compensation?
The flight is one PNR, airline is Aegean and the flight is from Tel Aviv to Nuremberg with connection in Athens and Thessaloniki. The flight is on October 1st and I received the notification on September 19th. My main concern is that when I agree to a rebooking a day later, I might lose my right to compensation but do not know if this is true or not

What’s your itinerary and what is the airline? On what date are you travelling?

‘Morally impossible’? Is this one ticket (one PNR) or a self-transfer?

It is one PNR, airline is Aegean and the flight is from Tel Aviv to Nuremberg with connection in Athens and Thessaloniki. The flight is on October 1st and I received the notification on September 19th. My main concern is that when I agree to a rebooking a day later, I might lose my right to compensation but do not know if this is true or not.

Please edit your question to add this information, so that this comment thread can be deleted.

I’m not sure I would agree to rebook to the next day flight/another airport because it too could be affected by a late schedule change. You have a connecting ticket and Aegean has an obligation to get you to your destination. If I were you I would consider sticking with the reschedule you have and see how it works out.
